# How to make SELECT more faster without NESTED LOOP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, loops, nested

Hello i'm making a website for webshop for t-shirts. Every product (from all 1400) has own ID (idedro), but every ID has different colors, sometimes one, sometimes twenty.
I need to show every product in own picture with all colors it has below, but i think a loop inside of a loop takes too much CPU time. Is there any way to make it with one loop may or [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pzc8.jpg)be with JOIN or prepared statments?

```
$querycount = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT (idedro) 
    FROM megadb WHERE catteniskiipotnici=1 ORDER BY idedro ASC");

  while ($rowcounts = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querycount)) {


  $result1 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT color 
    FROM megadb WHERE idedro='$rowcounts[idedro]'");

       while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) { echo $row1[color]; } 
      }
```

Comment: This question has a lot of depth to it.  You're asking about data pagination, and my guess is that this would be handled well with a good front-end library.  Are you using Kendo, Angular, React, or some other front-end library?

Comment: No i don't use any library. Every page will have 52 products on it with pics and than under the pic will have small squares representing the colors.

Comment: The solution below will work, I guess.  I'd personally suggest reorganizing your architecture a bit.  Using a more modern front-end than raw code would lead to easier implementation of what you want.  The output I would want to send to the client environment, in this case, would be a dataset that included all the rows in an INNER JOIN query, then the client would format that cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want using [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT idedro, group_concat(color)
FROM megadb 
WHERE catteniskiipotnici=1 
GROUP BY idedro
ORDER BY idedro ASC
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5b67/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE megadb
    (`idedro` int, `color` varchar(5), `catteniskiipotnici` int)
;

INSERT INTO megadb
    (`idedro`, `color`, `catteniskiipotnici`)
VALUES
    (1, 'blue', 1),
    (2, 'blue', 1),
    (2, 'red', 1),
    (3, 'blue', 1),
    (3, 'red', 1),
    (3, 'white', 1),
    (4, 'blue', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
    SELECT idedro, group_concat(color)
    FROM megadb 
    WHERE catteniskiipotnici=1 
    GROUP BY idedro
    ORDER BY idedro ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e5b67/2/0)**:

```
| idedro | group_concat(color) |
|--------|---------------------|
|      1 |                blue |
|      2 |            blue,red |
|      3 |      blue,red,white |
```

Comment: @BorislavGanev you're welcome, careful with [group concat](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you need to set the `group_concat_max_len` mySQL variable to something bigger than the default 1024 byte (take a look at the doc for how to)